# Flatten a multi-dimensional array in VBA?

Tags: arrays, vba

Suppose I have two multi-dimensional arrays of the same rank/shape (which can be determined, but at the time of writing the code it is unknown). How can I add one of these arrays to the other programmatically, ie. without doing this:

```
Select Case Rank
    Case 1
        A(i) = A(i) + B(i)
    Case 2
        A(i, j) = A(i, j) + B(i, j)
    Case 3
        A(i, j, k) = A(i, j, k) + B(i, j, k)
Etc
```

I don't think I can do it with For Each. Is there a way to access the items by a flat index? Assume that I know the total number of elements in the array.

One possible method is with SafeArrayAllocDescriptor without allocating the data, and then "borrow" the data pointer to the temporary safearray, but it sounds really cumbersome.

Another is with CopyMemory by reading and writing one element at a time, but I'm guessing it will be slow.

Comment: With flatten, do you mean merge two into one or do addition (+)? Because guess what you may, arrays are really damn quick and afaik, there's no way to do that in one go.

Comment: I mean to access its element as if it was a vector (any multi-dimensional array), but for each is not an option here.

Comment: Possibly by manipulating the safe array descriptor if all the same data type might be able to flatten multidimensional arrays into one dimension.   Off top of my head would need to obtain the safe array structure, update CDims and cElements . Been a while since playing around with managed safearrays, if all the same scalar type might be continuous memory.   Would recommend some way to memory dump to check that. Concept obtain safe array descriptor for the source arrays, create managed one dimsional safearrays calculate cElements and obtain pvData from sources arrays. etc

Comment: Would take same time to  do a solution and test. [ManagedCharSafeArray](https://github.com/MarkJohnstoneGitHub/VBA-IDictionary/blob/master/scr/ManagedCharSafeArray.cls) is an example of a managed safe array. May require update TypeSafeArray.bas structure as the padding might not be corrrect.  Require two managed safe arrays to flatten out the source arrays to one dimension, calculation for cElements, obtain data pointer from the source array descriptors. Use managed arrays as one dim arrays for addition. Make sure set data pointers to null for managed arrays when finished.

Comment: The trick with altering the safearray in-place worked beautifully. I'm only changing cDims and the first UBound. I think I've seen some of the linked code earlier, btw. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @drgs Nice my old code might of helped. Careful if manipulating the memory of the SA descriptors of the source arrays and should reset them to original settings before going out of scope or before it effects other code using the source arrays, otherwise  may cause issues with VBA garbage collection. IMO safer to create a separate "overlay"/managed safe array as long as dispose of them i.e. reset the data pointes & cElements to null. Overall the technique might come in handy for matrix mathematics in VBA.

Comment: @M. Johnstone I think it would be good to place an answer. Since our main purpose here is to make as many as possible people learning, I am sure that this way will be interested for a lot of users. Placing the link to the necessary module and some general considerations, an example maybe... I will definitely vote it up.

Comment: I can put together an answer with some code later on. Btw, did some tests with a 1000x1000 matrix, a simple operation of incrementing all items by one, run a hundred times. Regular matrix (A(i,j) = A(i,j) +1) -- ca 4-4.2 sec. Flat mode (A(i) = A(i) +1) - 2,4-2,7 sec. I guess the difference will be greater for 3D tensors etc.

Comment: @M. Johnstone No any rush... Please, show the example you mentioned in your above comment and anything you think may be relevant/instructive.

Comment: @FaneDuru Thanks no rush.  Slightly preoccupied attempting some COM interop. Similar [ManagedCharSafeArray](https://github.com/MarkJohnstoneGitHub/VBA-IDictionary/blob/master/scr/ManagedCharSafeArray.cls) Modify with  AllocateData(sourceArray), pvData = the pointer to the source array data, cElements = number of total elements in the multi-dimensional arrray (probably the tricky bit to figure out).  Maybe make flexible for other scalar numeric types and add a sprinkle of error handling.  Got the ball rolling and appears drgs got the concepts.  Quick peek their solutions looks great.

Answer (score 2):

Using advice from M. Johnstone, here is a matrix class with a flatten method below.

```
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim t As Long
Dim matA As clsMatrix
Dim A() As Double
Dim lngStart As Long
Dim lngEnd As Long

Set matA = New clsMatrix
matA.Resize 1000, 1000

matA.CreateAlias A
lngStart = GetTickCount()
For t = 1 To 100
    For i = 1 To matA.NumRows
        For j = 1 To matA.NumCols
            A(i, j) = A(i, j) + 1
        Next j
    Next i
Next t
lngEnd = GetTickCount()
MsgBox (lngEnd - lngStart) / 1000 '4-5 sec on average
matA.RemoveAlias A


matA.CreateAlias A
matA.Flatten
lngStart = GetTickCount()
For t = 1 To 100
    For i = 1 To matA.Size
        A(i) = A(i) + 1
    Next i
Next t
lngEnd = GetTickCount()
MsgBox (lngEnd - lngStart) / 1000 '2-3 sec on average
matA.Unflatten
matA.RemoveAlias A
```

clsMatrix Class:

```
Option Explicit

Public Const NULL_PTR As LongPtr = 0^

Public Const SIZEOF_VBA_INTEGER As Long = 2&
Public Const SIZEOF_VBA_LONG As Long = 4&
Public Const SIZEOF_VBA_SINGLE As Long = 4&
Public Const SIZEOF_VBA_DOUBLE As Long = 8&

#If Win64 Then
    Public Const SIZEOF_VBA_LONGPTR As Long = 8&
    Public Const OFFSET_RGSABOUND As Long = 24&
#Else
    Public Const SIZEOF_VBA_LONGPTR As Long = 4&
    Public Const OFFSET_RGSABOUND As Long = 16&
#End If

Private Const NUM_DIMENSIONS As Long = 2&

Private Declare PtrSafe Function SafeArrayLock Lib "oleaut32.dll" (ByVal psa As LongPtr) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function SafeArrayUnlock Lib "oleaut32.dll" (ByVal psa As LongPtr) As Long

Private mlngNumRows As Long
Private mlngNumCols As Long
Private madblArray() As Double
Private mptrSafeArray As LongPtr
Private mptrData As LongPtr

Public Property Get NumRows() As Long
    NumRows = mlngNumRows
End Property

Public Property Get NumCols() As Long
    NumCols = mlngNumCols
End Property

Public Property Get Size() As Long
    Size = mlngNumRows * mlngNumCols
End Property

Public Property Get Data() As LongPtr
    Data = mptrData
End Property

Public Sub Resize(ByRef lngNumRows As Long, _
                  ByRef lngNumCols As Long)
    If lngNumRows < 1 Then
        LogError "clsMatrix.Resize", "lngNumRows < 1"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If lngNumCols < 1 Then
        LogError "clsMatrix.Resize", "lngNumCols < 1"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    mlngNumRows = lngNumRows
    mlngNumCols = lngNumCols
    ReDim madblArray(1 To mlngNumRows, 1 To mlngNumCols)
    CopyMemory mptrSafeArray, ByVal VarPtrArray(madblArray), SIZEOF_VBA_LONGPTR
    mptrData = VarPtr(madblArray(1, 1))
End Sub

Public Sub Flatten()
    If mptrSafeArray = NULL_PTR Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    CopyMemory ByVal mptrSafeArray, 1, SIZEOF_VBA_INTEGER 'Set cDims to 1
    CopyMemory ByVal mptrSafeArray + OFFSET_RGSABOUND, Me.Size, SIZEOF_VBA_LONG 'Set first UBound to total number of elements
End Sub

Public Sub Unflatten()
    If mptrSafeArray = NULL_PTR Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    CopyMemory ByVal mptrSafeArray, NUM_DIMENSIONS, SIZEOF_VBA_INTEGER 'Set cDims back to 2
    CopyMemory ByVal mptrSafeArray + OFFSET_RGSABOUND, mlngNumCols, SIZEOF_VBA_LONG 'Set first UBound back to number of columns (dimensions appear in reverse order)
End Sub

Public Sub CreateAlias(ByRef adblAlias() As Double)
    Dim lngErrorCode As Long
    
    lngErrorCode = SafeArrayLock(mptrSafeArray)
    If lngErrorCode Then
        LogError "clsMatrix.CreateAlias", "lngErrorCode", lngErrorCode, GetSystemMessage(lngErrorCode)
        Exit Sub
    End If
    CopyMemory ByVal VarPtrArray(adblAlias), mptrSafeArray, SIZEOF_VBA_LONGPTR
End Sub

Public Sub RemoveAlias(ByRef adblAlias() As Double)
    Dim lngErrorCode As Long
    
    lngErrorCode = SafeArrayUnlock(mptrSafeArray)
    If lngErrorCode Then
        LogError "clsMatrix.RemoveAlias", "lngErrorCode", lngErrorCode, GetSystemMessage(lngErrorCode)
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ZeroMemory ByVal VarPtrArray(adblAlias), SIZEOF_VBA_LONGPTR
End Sub
```